# Let $A\in Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $T:Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(X)=AX$ Calculate $\det(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A\in Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $T:Mat_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(X)=AX$ Calculate $\det(T)$

**My work:**

My definition: $\det(T)=\sum _{\sigma\in G_n}ε(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}$

Let $B=\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\}$ a basis of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ then

$\det_B(T(A_1),\cdots,T(A_n))=\alpha\det_B(A_1,\cdots,A_n)$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$

Moreover
$\det_B(T(A_1),\cdots,T(A_n))=\det_B(A_1X,...,A_nX)$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: What is the dimension of $\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ again? Besides, I cannot make sense of any of your computations, but it is perhaps just me, $\det$ is real valued map, so $\det_B(\cdots)=\det(A)X$ is strange...

Comment: the dimension of that space is $n^2$ @C.Falcon yes, yo have reason here.... i think that step have a mistake.

Comment: How is $T(X) \in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ when $A \in Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Yes, exactly! So why do you take a set of cardinality $n$ as a basis of this space? Do you know any simple basis $\{E_{i,j}\}_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ of $\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$? And what $T(E_{i,j})$ would be for this choice?

Comment: Hint: can you describe the eigenspaces of $T$, assuming $A$ is diagonalizable?  (And then you can use that the diagonalizable matrices are dense in $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$.)

Comment: i can't use eigenspaces in this exercise!! :l @DanielSchepler but thanks Daniel!

Comment: @C.Falcon i take the elements of $B$ how columns of the matrix

Comment: The columns of a matrix never make a basis of $\operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$, but a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if this matrix is invertible. I don't follow you there, a basis must have cardinality $n^2$ as you stated.

Comment: @Bvss12:  why can't you use eigenspaces?  Forbidden by your prof?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes,
I have not seen the theory of eigenvalues ​​formally.

Comment: @Bvss12:  OK.  Thanks.

Comment: I think could be a basis... thanks for that correction @C.Falcon

Answer (score 4):

Here's one eigenvalue-free approach: let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$ (consisting of column-vectors).  We compute the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis
$$
\mathcal B = (e_1^Te_1,e_2e_1^T,\dots,e_ne_1^T,\\
\qquad e_1^Te_2,e_2e_2^T,\dots,e_ne_2^T,\\
\vdots\\
\qquad e_1^Te_n,e_2e_n^T,\dots,e_ne_n^T)
$$
To be the block-diagonal matrix
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = 
\pmatrix{A&0& \cdots & 0\\
0&A&\ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & A
}
$$
Show that the determinant of this matrix is $\det(A)^n$.

Comment: Thanks, is easy to show det$([T]_{\mathcal B}) $ because is a diagonal matrix. then his determinant is $det(A).det(A)...det(A)^n$ but i dont understand very good your notation. $\mathcal B = (e_1^Te_1,e_2e_1^T,\dots,e_ne_1^T,\\
\qquad e_1^Te_2,e_2e_2^T,\dots,e_ne_2^T,\\
\vdots\\
\qquad e_1^Te_n,e_2e_n^T,\dots,e_ne_n^T)$ $B$ is a basis of $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$? the canonical basis? only that?

Comment: So, for instance:
$$
e_2e_1^T = \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\ \vdots \\ 0} \pmatrix{1&0&0&\cdots & 0} = \pmatrix{0&0&0& \cdots & 0\\1&0&0&\cdots & 0\\
0 &0&0&\cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots&\vdots\\
0 & 0 &0 & \cdots & 0}
$$

Comment: oh, thanks for that